Flutter select a checkbox from ListViewBuilder
I'm streaming data from Firestore and displaying a ListView.Builder.
I want to add a checkbox to each item in the ListTile. I also want to be able to select an individual checkbox but this is where the problem comes in. I tried the code below but the boxes aren't selecting. How can I select individual checkboxes and later delete the list of the selected boxes?
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>? items = [];
List<bool>? isChecking = List<bool>.filled(items!.length, false);
StreamBuilder(
   stream: ....
   builder:(context, snapshot){
       return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            items = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListTile(
            onTap: () {.... },
             leading: CheckBox(
             value: isChecking[index],
             onChanged: (val){
                 setState(() {
                     isChecking[index] = val!;
                   });
               }
             )
           );
        }
         
     );
   }
)


The checkbox will display as checked/unchecked based on what is passed to its value parameter, which seems to be missing from your code. Try changing to:
CheckBox(
  value: isChecking[index] // this line added
  onChanged: (val){
    setState(() {
      isChecking[index] = val!;
    });
  }
)

(assuming isChecking is a state parameter - make sure that line that sets it to a list of False is not overwriting the list every time build runs!)

Actually, I have it in my code but I forgot to add it here. Even with the full code, I can't still select

I see the edit to the question, thanks! is it possible that the isChecking list is being overwritten as all false on each build? then whenever you try to check an item, it will rebuild, be set to false, and show up as unchecked

I'm sorry but I don't understand.

It's a bit hard to see just from the code snippet, so I was wondering if the List<bool>? isChecking = List<bool>.filled(items!.length, false); line was located in the build function or somewhere else. If it's in build, then when you select the checkbox, setState will cause a rebuild, meaning that line gets run, setting the list to all False (which is not what you want - you want the checked ones to be True).

I tried both in the build function and in the class state but non is working

When I debug it it gives me the error
Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (length): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

that error means you tried to access item 0 of an empty list. is it possible you aren't maintaining the length of the list properly as items get added?

I can't really tell. The whole code of the Checkbox is what I put here. Maybe there is something I need to do that I don't know.
